# using pdfstartlink

Tags: pdftex, viewers

I am using

```
\def\recordjump#1#2#3{%
\pdfstartlink
      attr{/Border [0 0 0]  }%
      user {%
        /Subtype /Link
        /A <<
          /F (#1.pdf)
          /S /GoToR
          /D[#2 /Fit]
        >>%
      }\textcolor{red}{#3}\pdfendlink}
```

to open a second pdf file from within the first one. Is there anyway to open the second file in a new window rather than replace the first one.

Sorry I forgot to say the the hyperlink and hypertarget are in different pdf files so Sebastian Rahtz produced the code above for me many years ago.

Peter

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you want to do this with such low-level features? There is hyperref which can do file links (without including the file) and packages like attachfile2 for file links including the file.

Comment: I'm not sure a MWE makes that much difference here: it's a fundamental question about how hyperlinks in PDFs work. (So arguably a 'core' question.)

Answer (score 4):

The PDF Specification provides the key `/NewWindow` for this purpose. Just insert

```
/NewWindow true
```

into the link action dictionary `/A<< ... >>`.