# How to make a link without getting additional functionality of hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, links

I have a document where I want to insert a clickable link to a web page, which can be achieved with the below code. The problem is the default behaviour of `hyperref` also makes things like my table of contents, references, citations, etc, into links as well. I only want this one url to be a link, literally nothing else. How do I turn off all these additional features?

Alternatively, is there another package I could use which will allow me to make links, but not give me all this other behaviour?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
text text text
\section{A title}
\url{http://www.google.com}
\section{Another title}
text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: @TeXnician Actually you can: You should load `hyperref` with the option `implicit=false`, which does not redefine the LaTeX internals.

Comment: @campa Oh right, I forgot about this option, because this does not always work on its own (e.g. for citations with biblatex which would need special treatment).

Comment: That option seems to work ok in my MWE, but my main document won't compile with ````hyperref```` loaded, regardless of whether it has that option or not. Not sure what's going on there. @TeXnician's suggestion of some postscript code could be a viable alternative. Could anyone talk me through how to get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple example for pdfLaTeX (border is disabled, just comment out the first line to enable it; see also [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408957/using-pdfstartlink)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myurl#1{%
\leavevmode\pdfstartlink
      attr{/Border [0 0 0]  }%
      user {%
        /Subtype /Link
        /A << /S /URI /URI (#1) >>%
      }\texttt{#1}\pdfendlink}

\begin{document}
    Test
    \myurl{www.example.com}
    Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work in this very simple case, but if I try to add it to a slightly more complex document, such as my MWE in the original question, I get an error saying pdfstartlink cannot be used in vertical mode. I managed an ad hoc solution by putting it in an mbox, but I don't know if this would create some undesirable behaviour such that it wouldn't work as a general solution, so it may need to be tweaked further.

Comment: My final code that I can use directly in the text is: ````\mbox{\pdfstartlink attr{/Border[0 0 0]} user{/Subtype /Link /A << /S /URI /URI (www.example.com) >>}{\color{blue}\textbf{\underline{Link Name}}}\pdfendlink}```` Note that I also call the ````color```` package in the preamble.

Comment: @Ulysses I added a fix.